# How to implement Android style permissions in a Django Application?

Tags: python, django, permissions

I have a Django applictation. This has `Users`, and `Groups`. In this application `Users` can be in `Groups`. Each of the `Users` has a `ID`, `Name`, `Address`, and `Job`. When a `Users` becomes a `Member` of a `Group`, the `User` has the choice of sharing his `Name`, `Address`, and `Job`. Depending on the `User's` choices will the others in that `Group` be able to see his `Name`, `Address`, and `Job`.

A possible way of making this work is by making a `Memberships` object. `Users` has a ManyToMany relation to `Groups` through this `Memberships` object. This object has a list of Booleans for each field. In the `__init__` of the serializer the fields that have not been shared, are dropped.

Is this a sensical way of doing this? Is there a more efficient way of doing this?

Comment: Hey - It sounds simpler to just add those fields to the user model. then you can just `{% if user.show_name %} {{ user.name }}`

Comment: The sharing is can be set for each Group, e.g. User A wants to share his Job with Group A, but not Group B. Including this in the User as you mentioned, would make the sharing option the same for all Groups, not dependent on the Group. The latter is what I am looking for.

Comment: Yep, your approach makes sense. Although I would describe all permissions with one ArrayField listing the field names for which sharing permission is given (if you’re using postgresql) because that way when adding new fields you don’t need to remember to change the Membership model and populate default values. It’s also easier to cycle through than through separate model fields.

Comment: That is a great suggestion. Thanks. (Can't upvote your comment, because I'm new)